# Export database with emoji

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro, datagrip

I would like to export my database with emoji, but I have a problem with the export. When I exported my table, the emoji are replaced by "?".

For example :

[image]

When I export, and import, I have this :

[image]

I checked my table (utf-8) :

[image]

I use Sequel Pro to export and import.

But if I tried with DataGrip, and I have directly the "?", I never see the emoji :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

before you run the queries, run

```
set names utf8mb4;
```

Why?

In short.

First, Emoji usually takes four bytes, however, mysql's `utf8`, an alias for for `utf8mb3`, using one to three bytes(i.e., max byte three), which could not understand an Emoji char. As such, you see a '?' in your result. `utf8mb4` can do the job since it requires a maximum of four bytes per multibyte character.

Second, `set names utf8mb4` will set three session variable, e.g.,

```
SET character_set_client = utf8mb4;
SET character_set_results = utf8mb4;
SET character_set_connection = utf8mb4;
```

which will coordinate the barrier between server, client and results char set, so we can view the Emoji correctly.

For more information, you can find in the doc

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, it would be a better answer if you [edit] it to explain why this works. A description of what `utf8mb4` is would be a good start.

Comment: @shoover hi, thank you for the advice and  I have add the explanation.